# Why Balance in Aurora shows like 0 in WETH?

Tags: hardhat, balances, aura

Have a question about my wallet balance Check Function in hardhat script.

It's always seeing like 0 but it's not.

My function:

```
let config,arb,owner;
const network = hre.network.name;
if (network === 'aurora') config = require('./../config/aurora.json');

const asset = config.baseAssets[i];
        const tokenAsset = await interface.attach(asset.address);
        const ownerBalance = await tokenAsset.balanceOf(owner.address);
        console.log(`${asset.sym} Owner Balance: `,ownerBalance.toString());
        const arbBalance = await arb.getBalance(asset.address);
        console.log(`${asset.sym} Arb Balance: `,arbBalance.toString());
  }
```

Aurora.json

```
"baseAssets": [
    { "sym": "usdc", "address": "0xB12BFcA5A55806AaF64E99521918A4bf0fC40802" },
    { "sym": "weth","address": "0xC9BdeEd33CD01541e1eeD10f90519d2C06Fe3feB" },
    { "sym": "wnear", "address": "0xC42C30aC6Cc15faC9bD938618BcaA1a1FaE8501d" },
    { "sym": "usdt", "address": "0x4988a896b1227218e4A686fdE5EabdcAbd91571f" },
    { "sym": "aurora", "address": "0x8BEc47865aDe3B172A928df8f990Bc7f2A3b9f79" },
    { "sym": "atust", "address": "0x5ce9F0B6AFb36135b5ddBF11705cEB65E634A9dC" }
    
  ],
```

Output:

```
Loaded 172 routes
Owner: 0x4Bea765324eEAD7eA16bC187e5492C4152EbFdd6
usdc 0
weth 0
wnear 0
usdt 0
aurora 0
atust 0
```

Real WETH Balance 0.01492 - and yes, i'm checked 3 times addresses